# swift global variable stays null in another class

Tags: ios, swift

So, I'm using swift and I'm pretty new at this. Basically what is happening is when I declare a global variable called points in my ViewController class, I give it a value and when I print it in that class, it prints the proper value. I than access the variable in another class, and it's always null. I want to access the value of the variable. This is my ViewController class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var points: UITextField! 

    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let pts: Int? = Int(points.text!) //This is where I use points to covert it to an int

        if(pts == 0) {
            checkPoints.text = "Minimum points allowed is 1!"
        }else if(pts! > 50) {
        checkPoints.text = "Maximum points allowed is 50!"
    }else{
        checkPoints.text = ""
        let farray = arrayOfNames.filter() {$0 != ""}
        if(farray.count > 0) {
            print("Game starting")
            print(arrayOfNames.count)
        }else{
            print("No players added")
            print(farray.count)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that I'm trying to access points from.

```
class test1212: UIViewController {

var previousViewController: ViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    previousViewController = ViewController()

}
@IBAction func test(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //for testing purposes, instead of converting points to an int, I just print it's string value...which doesn't work
    print(previousViewController.points.text!)

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by two way but don't create instance to your **ViewController().**

@Benjamin Lowry is suggested way.
If you want all over **ViewController().**, just make **String** (what ever you want) in **AppDelegate**.

Declare your property

```
var point = String()
```

above following line

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

Then directly assign your values to that property.

```
 point = points.text!
```

In your

**playButton** action method.

And directly access it from your **test1212** class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     print(point)

}
```

Don't forget to update **point** if you don't need any more.

Answer (score 2):

In your test1212 ViewController in `viewDidLoad` you have the following line:

```
previousViewController = ViewController()
```

What this does is create a new instance of that view controller and assign it to your variable. This means that your `points` textField will have no value by default.

The way you are supposed to do this type of data transfer is through using a `prepareForSegue`. When you segue from your first controller to your second controller you should be doing something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {

        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? test1212 {

            destinationVC.pointsText = self.points.text

        }
    }
}
```

This would require you to create a `pointsText` String variable in your test1212 class, but then you could easily pass the value when moving from the first VC to the second VC.

Comment: So I wrote in the code you had and I added pointsText as a string variable in my test1212 class like this: var pointsText:String! ....But when i print out pointsText i get an error because it says it found a nil by unwrapping an optional value

Comment: Make sure you've also set the identifier for your segue to "mySegue". If you do, then the above code should work.